# Bind a function to Bootstrap Modal Close by ESC key

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I know we can bind a function to bootstrap modal for close event like this:

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){ 
    //run the script
});
```

But this only works when you close the modal by clicking on grey area or clicking on close button in Firefox. However whenever I try to close the modal by ESC key my script is running. I don't want to disable ESC key for closing bootstrap modal.
Is there any solution to detect closing modal by pressing escape in bootstrap in Firefox?

You can check a sample
 [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/8vvx9bkc/). In this example In firefox if you play the YouTube video in the modal with and close the modal by pressing escape the video doesn't stop but if you click on close button or click on grey area then the close functions works properly and clear the iframe src so video stops.

Comment: Can you share your code in snippet ?

Comment: **[I think it works with ESC key](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/bc6bq2no/1/)**

Comment: I just added an example in the question which shows it doesn't work on escape key but works in other situations.

Comment: @billynoah Sorry I forgot to say to add tabindex="-1" to the modal div to enable esc key.

Comment: @billynoah I changed my example link to jsfiddle and made a new one there. I noticed its working fine in chrome but the problem appears in firefox. can you check the new link with firefox please?

Comment: @billynoah Have you tried my new jsfiddle in firefox? the video stopped after closing the modal by esc key? So wired I am using firefox 47 in mac and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Yes, actually I am also using Firefox 47 on a Mac and yes it stopped.

Comment: I think you secretly might just want me to watch bunny cartoons.

Comment: @billynoah for me ESC key closes the modal but I still can hear the sounds of the movie. it means youtube is still playing but as modal is disappeared i just can't see it. Is you computer sound mute when you were testing it?

Comment: Oh yeah.. that's odd.  Even more odd is when I add an alert in the close event it really does stop playing.

Comment: You can see in a web inspector that the attribute does get cleared though so it's just a firefox bug it would seem.

Comment: @billynoah the problem was solved by Kuldeep Vithlani. He added a timeout to hide modal function and now its working fine in Firefox.

Comment: another solution:  https://jsfiddle.net/8vvx9bkc/2/

Comment: @billynoah yes this one is working fine too. Thank you very much. You can add this as an answer so I can vote it up too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put below code for close event of your modal. It will also work with esc button.

```
$("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
     setTimeout(function(){
    $("#cartoonVideo").attr('src','');
    });    
});
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vvx9bkc/1/) for this.

Comment: No I think you didn't notice the problem properly. If you add tabindex="-1" to this, the modal pops out but when you play the youtube video and click outside the iframe and then press key as you mentioned, the modal will close but the video doesn't stop. because youtube iframe src is not cleared. but if you close it by click on grey area or close icon then the video stops. So it means the modal close function didn't work properly on pressing esc button

Comment: As per your suggestion I have put alert inside bootstrap hide event. So first I played video after that I have clicked in the header of the modal. And after that I pressed escape and it shows me alert. It also stops video as expected.

Comment: I noticed the problem appears in Firefox and not in chrome. please test it with firefox. I changed my example link to jsfiddle. you can test it now

Comment: Could you try this jsfiddle. I think this should work now. https://jsfiddle.net/8vvx9bkc/1/

Comment: Thanks Kuldeep. it solved the problem. I guess settimeout solved it. Please edit your answer and update it with the solution so I can give you vote up

Comment: Updated my answer. Thanks. :)

Comment: @KuldeepVithlani hi it does not work at my end could you please guide me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/295137/magento-2-resize-and-draggable-modal-popup

Answer (score 2):

After a bazillion back and forths I came up with this so figured I'd add it as another possible solution.  Creating and destroying the iframe with the modal.  I've seen behavior like this with Firefox before and found `setTimeout()` to sometimes work and other times behave inconsistently.  With this method you are guaranteed that the `<iframe>` will truly be cleared:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myModal").on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
    $("#cartoonVideo").remove();
  });
  $("#myModal").on('show.bs.modal', function() {
    $('#myModal .modal-body').html('<iframe id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/YE7VzlLtp-4" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="bs-example">
  <!-- Button HTML (to Trigger Modal) -->
  <a href="#myModal" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" data-toggle="modal">Launch Demo Modal</a>

  <!-- Modal HTML -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">YouTube Video</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works fine. Thanks

Comment: Thanks - I learned about another idiosyncrasy of Firefox trying to figure this out.